# PHP imagecreatefromjpeg() Failing with a large image

Tags: php, memory, limit

I have a script for cropping images which appears to be failing when I call 'imagecreatefromjpeg()', when creating the image from the source file.

It works for most images, even of a large filesize, one test file of 16mb works fine.

However one image keeps failing, this image is much larger in terms of dimensions and dpi than the others however only 1.4mb in file size.

It's 8000px by 5600px and 300dpi.

Does anyone have any experience with this or any ideas on on why it would be failing?

PHP does report the max memory usage on the script. memory_limit is currently set to 128mb server side.

Thank you in advance

Comment: set debug mode to on and test. I am assuming the memory needs to be changed. I has a similar thind and got this error 'The requested URL /<br /><b>Fatal error</b>: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 56000 bytes) in '

Comment: Rule of thumb byte calculation for working with images, width x height x 4 bytes for ARGB for a single image, x2 for manipulation.... 8000x5600x4x2 = 358,400,000 bytes, = 358M... that's the minimum memory required to use an image of those dimensions

Comment: thank you. to what value did you boost your memory_limit too?

Comment: thank you mark, do you have a source for this calculation, for reference reasons?

Comment: No source that I could locate quickly, just common sense (and prior knowledge).... With GD, you're loading to a fully-expanded bitmap with 4 channels (ARGB).... and any manipulation requires the original and the manipulated version of that bitmap (hence the x2)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for the insight, not familiar with GD all that much however what you have explained makes sense. *thumbs up*